# Apache mod rewrite like twitter url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Here is my .htaccess code

```
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
  Options -Multiviews

  RewriteEngine On

 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile?username=$1 [NC,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d
 RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /$1/$2.php 
 RewriteRule ^s/([^/]*)$ /s.php?share=$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
 RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I would users on my website to be able to access their profile like how twitter does. For instance www.mywebsite.com/Jim  would actually be rewritten as www.mywebsite.com/profile?username=Jim.

Currently the only part of the code that works is allowing url without the php extension. For instance www.mywebsite.com/home instead of www.mywebsite.com/home.php.

Moreover, the rewrite rule for s.php does not work like it should. I would like the page www.mywebsite.com/s/123456 to be written as www.mywebsite.com/s?share=12345.

I don't if the order of my htaccess is wrong but none of these seem to work. Additionally when a page is not found I'm still getting the default Apache 404 even though I have a rewrite rule to 404.php

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect needs to be first, then your profile, then your share, then the most generalized php extension:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d
RewriteRule ^s/([^/]*)$ /s.php?share=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

Comment: Its still not working. I tried chiecking my /etc/apache2/sites-available to see if allowoveride is enable and its set to all but it is still not working. Is there anything else I need to be doing? Please see the edits in my question for the etc/apache2/sitesavailable/default file